# MPSImageGaussianBlur in a rendering pipeline

Tags: metal

I've got a `MPSImageGaussianBlur` object doing work on each frame of a compute pass (Blurring the contents of an intermediate texture).

While the app is still running at 60fps no problem, I see an increase of ~15% in CPU usage when enabling the blur pass. I'm wondering if this is normal?

I'm just curious as to what could be going on under the hood of `MPSImageGaussianBlur`'s `encodeToCommandBuffer:` operation that would see so much CPU utilization. In my (albeit naive) understanding, I'd imagine there would just be some simple encoding along the lines of:

***`MPSImageGaussianBlur.encodeToCommandBuffer:` pseudo-method :***

```
func encodeToCommandBuffer(commandBuffer: MTLCommandBuffer, sourceTexture: MTLTexture, destinationTexture: MTLTexture) {

    let encoder = commandBuffer.computeCommandEncoder()
    encoder.setComputePipelineState(...)

    encoder.setTexture(sourceTexture, atIndex: 0)
    encoder.setTexture(destinationTexture, atIndex: 1)

    // kernel weights would be built at initialization and 
    // present here as a `kernelWeights` property
    encoder.setTexture(self.kernelWeights, atIndex: 2)

    let threadgroupsPerGrid = ...
    let threadsPerThreadgroup = ...
    encoder.dispatchThreadgroups(threadgroupsPerGrid, threadsPerThreadgroup: threadsPerThreadgroup)
    encoder.endEncoding()
}
```

Most of the 'performance magic' would be implemented on the algorithms running in the compute kernel function. I can appreciate that bit because performance (on the GPU) is pretty fantastic independent of the blurRadius I initialize the `MPSImageGaussianBlur` with.

Some probably irrelevant details about my specific setup:

- `MPSImageGaussianBlur` initialized with blur radius 8 pixels.
- The texture I'm blurring is 128 by 128 pixels.
- Performing all rendering in an MTKViewDelegate's `drawInMTKView:` method.

I hope this question is somewhat clear in it's intent.

Comment: Just to be sure, you're only creating one instance of `MPSImageGaussianBlur`, and reusing it across frames, correct?

Comment: Yep, Just one instance

Comment: Which device and iOS version are you seeing this behavior on?

Comment: I'm running it on an iPhone 6 with iOS 9.3. I'm using Xcode 7.3 beta 4 and tracking the CPU usage both in instruments as well as the build in debug navigator. Thanks for looking into this!

Comment: One more detail: When you say ~15% are you saying 15 percentage points, or 15% additional CPU usage? If the latter, I would say that's expected. If the former, it sounds like a fairly major regression. What's your typical blur radius (sigma)?

Comment: The latter, I'll see about 20% CPU usage in the app with the blur pass disabled, and about 35% with it enabled. Sigma is 8 for the blur. I don't see much difference in CPU usage (It's fairly constant at ~15%) when I increase or decrease sigma. I suppose I'd expect that since, assuming the kernel is computed on the initialization of `MPSImageGaussianBlur`, the only overhead associated with the kernel size would be the size of the chunk of memory the CPU needs to copy over to GPU each pass, right?

Comment: Empirically, it looks like `encodeToCommandBuffer:...` spends about 3/4 of its time in `MIAutoCache::GetTempTexture`, so I think you can chalk most of the CPU usage up to MPS doing internal buffer bookkeeping of this sort. If you find the overhead unacceptable, you should file a Radar with Apple, including a sample project if possible.

Comment: Ahh, that's a little disappointing (here I was hoping I was terribly misunderstanding something!). I'll keep poking around and file the Radar if nothing else. Thanks again for looking into this. Also, really enjoying your Metal By Example book!

Answer (score 2):

MPSGaussianBlur is internally a complex multipass algorithm. It is spending some time allocating textures out of its internal texture cache to hold the intermediate data. There is the overhead of multiple kernel launches to be managed. Also some resources like Gaussian blur kernel weights need to be set up. When you commit the command buffer, all these textures need to be wired down (iOS) and some other work needs to be done. So, it is not quite as simple as you imagine.

The texture you are using is small enough that the relatively fixed CPU overhead can start to become an appreciable part of the time.

Filing a radar on the CPU cost of MPSGassianBlur would cause Apple to spend an hour or two looking if something can be improved, and will be worth your time.

Answer (score -1):

I honestly would not be surprised if under the hood the gpu was being less accessed than you would think for the kernel.  In my first experiences with metal compute I found performance underwhelming and fell back again on neon.  It was counter intuitive. I really wouldn't be surprised if the cpu hit was neon.  I saw the same using mps Gaussian.  It would be nice to get this confirmed.  Neon has a lot of memory and instruction features that are friendlier to this use case.

Also, an indicator that this might be the case is that these filters don't run on OS X Metal.  If it were just compute shaders I'm sure they could run.  But Neon code can't run on the simulator.

Comment: No MPS workloads run on the CPU. There is no available method to ensure the correct timing on CPU work in the middle of a metal command buffer.